# Will defer be waiting until subroutine finishes execution?

Tags: go, goroutine, subroutine, defer-keyword

I have such function:

```
func TestDefer(lock sync.RWMutex, wait time.Duration) {

    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()

    // start goroutine 
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(wait)
    }()
}
```

I am eager to know when `lock.Unlock()` will be executed? Is it synchronized with subroutine `go func()` ? Will it be waiting until it finishes?

Comment: The documentation is clear: `defer`ed calls execute *when the function returns*. A goroutine runs concurrently, and therefor has no impact on the calling function's return timing. So, no, there is no reason why it would "wait" for the goroutine to finish, nor should it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Defer will not wait for your go routine to finish.
IF you want to do that, wait till the go routine is done executing using `sync.WaitGroup`.

```
func TestDefer(lock sync.RWMutex, wait time.Duration) {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()

    wg.Add(1)
    // start goroutine 
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(wait)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No, as soon as the `go` statement finishes its execution (that is, the Go runtime creates a new goroutine and puts it on some run queue), the execution of the function continues, and since the function's body ends there,
the functions deferred in it will run.

Synchronization between goroutines only ever happens explicitly—by means of channel operations of using primitives from the packages of the `sync` hierarchy.